# I'm having a render error in my nuxt page with a property that cannot be read

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to add rows to a table dynamically with a method in nuxt.js, but the prop that I have defined doesn't work...
I receive this error from the console:
Property or method "invoice_customer" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

I'm trying with this template:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>Customers</h3>
    <input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Search for names..." />
    <table v-if="customers.length > 0">
      <tr>
          <th>name</th>
          <th>address</th>
      </tr>
        <tr v-for="customer in customers" :key="customer.id">
          <td>{{ customer.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ customer.address }}</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <div class="center">
      <p>Customer</p>
      <select v-if="customers.length > 0">
        <option v-for="customer in customers" :key="customer.id">
          {{ customer.name }}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <table v-if="invoice_customers.length > 0">
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th>Expire Date</th>
          <th>Note</th>
        </tr>
        <tr
          v-for="invoice_customers in invoice_customer"
          :key="invoice_customers.id"
        >
          <td>
            <input
              type="number"
              name=""
              id=""
              v-model="invoice_customer.amount"
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            <b-form-datepicker
              id="example-datepicker"
              v-model="invoice_customer.expire_date"
              class="mb-2"
            ></b-form-datepicker>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="" id="" v-model="invoice_customer.note" />
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <b-button variant="outline-success" @click="addNewInstallment">+ Add New</b-button>
  </div>
</template>
```

and this is my script:

```html
<script>
export default {
  name: "IndexPage",
  data() {
    return {
      selected: "",
      customers: [],
      search: "",

      invoice_customers: [{
        id: 0,
        amount: 0,
        expire_date: "",
        note: "",
      }],
    };
  },
  props: {
  },

  async mounted() {
    const response = await this.$axios.$get("/api/customers");
    this.customers = response.data;
    return this.customers.filter((p) => {
      // return true if the product should be visible

      // in this example we just check if the search string
      // is a substring of the product name (case insensitive)
      return p.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) != -1;
    });
  },

  methods: {
    addNewInstallment() {    
      this.invoice_customers.push({
        id: 0,
        amount: 0,
        expire_date: "",
        note: "",
      });
    }
  }
  }
</script>
```

invoice customer is defined in v-for cycle

Comment: Btw, so you have any feedback on your other questions? I gave some input there too: https://stackoverflow.com/users/20780066/4ri37ix-l?tab=questions

Comment: yes I solved the problem but user that gave me the correct answer deleted the post, i don't know why, anyway I've added v-if and I verify that customer.lenght>0 as you can see in the code, it's the same project

Comment: It was deleted because it was answered by an AI (chat GPT), an admin deleted it. You can accept another answer, the result will be similar.

Answer (score 0):

You inverted the order in your `v-for`, it should be

```js
v-for="invoice_customer in invoice_customers"
```

Comment: thank uu, now I can create new rows but the form inside the table are visualized bad, how can insert form in a cell correctly?

Comment: If that one is solved, mark it as so and create a new question with the current formatting and the one you actually want. Please be specific too because "bad" is not enough. @4ri37ixL